# What is the point of Java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

**Why does Java RMI exist? Who uses it and for what?**

My most pressing questions;

- Why would you want to make calls to methods that aren't defined on your machine? Wouldn't it take much longer to execute? I don't see how this makes the world a better place. Wouldn't it just be smarter to have many machines running the complete program rather than many machines each running parts?
- Doesn't the fact that you have to manually provide interfaces to all the machines (clients and servers) kill whatever benefits having remote objects provides? In other words, if a benefit of having a remote object is that the client programmer doesn't have to interact with the server programmer, then doesn't it get annoying to have manually contact eachother to update the interfaces on both sides for each little change?
- How is this similar or different to a typical web app set up where a client communicates with a server? In my mind, HTTP calls are much easier to understand. Can an RMI Server require some sort of password from RMI clients?
- What kind of applications are typically made using Java RMI? Any hard examples?

Comment: RMI gives you marshalling and type safety, which you don't get with HTTP. Having said that, you've listed many of the reasons why it has fallen out of fashion. Restful web services are platform independent and much more lightweight

Comment: @JuanMendes You can't say that RMI has 'fallen out of favour' when it is the basis of J2EE. Restful Web services are neither more platform-independent nor more lighweight than RMI.

Comment: @ejp if you don't consider Java a platform, that is true. I was simply talking about being able to communicate with any language. It has fallen out of favor, can you really compare the number of services available as RMI with HTTP? J2EE is a java platform so it makes sense to use RMI. If you want others to consume your services, most will go with web services

Comment: @JuanMendez I made no attempt to compare the number of services available as RMI versus HTTP.  I have no information about it: neither I suspect do you; and in any case it is comparing apples to oranges. The fact is that most RMI usages are deeply hidden inside other frameworks and aren't visible to you or me. If you have some specific evidence for your unsubstantiated claims, it is up to you to produce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does Java RMI exist?

Err, because [Sun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) built it? The same Sun that provided [*Sun RPC*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_RPC).

> Who uses it and for what?

[RMI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) is the basis of [Jakarta EE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) (formerly J2EE) just to name one small example. However the concept of [remote method calls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_object_communication) dates further back to at least [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), and the concept of [remote procedure calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) to at least the 1970s. Sun provided their implementation of RPC in about 1982 and it is the basis of [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) among other things.

> Why would you want to make calls to methods that aren't defined on your machine?

Err, if you wanted them to run on another machine?

> Wouldn't it take much longer to execute?

Of course.

> I don't see how this makes the world a better place. Wouldn't it just be smarter to have many machines running the complete program rather than many machines each running parts?

So you've never heard of [distributed computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing), then?

> Doesn't the fact that you have to manually provide interfaces to all the machines (clients and servers) kill whatever benefits having remote objects provides?

No.

> In other words, if a benefit of having a remote object is that the client programmer doesn't have to interact with the server programmer

Did somebody say that was a benefit?

> then doesn't it get annoying to have manually contact each other to update the interfaces on both sides for each little change?

There don't tend to be many 'little changes', if you actually design your system before implementing it. But that isn't the only development model anyway. You could have a third person developing the interface. Or the same person developing both sides. Or have the remote interface defined by a specification. Or ...

> How is this similar or different to a typical web app set up where a client communicates with a server?

It uses RMI instead of [HTTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

> In my mind, HTTP calls are much easier to understand.

You can't get much easier to understand than a remote interface, but obviously your mileage varies.

> Can an RMI Server require some sort of password from RMI clients?

Yes, it can use mutually-authenticated [TLS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for example, or arbitrary authentication protocols implemented via custom socket factories.

Comment: I'm not sure I asked the question perfectly, but your answer helped. Thanks